# Обработчик события размера контентной области Scrollpane в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Нужно получить внутренний размер (`width/height`) контентной области объекта `Scrollpane`, при его изменении.
Имеется введу не ширина/высота самого объекта на сцене, а размер его контентной области (то, что скролиться).

**Пример:**

Есть объект `Scrollpane` с шириной и высотой на сцене 200x200, на него я помещаю несколько дочерних объектов (пускай это будут объекты `Image`), каждый из которых имеет разные габариты, к примеру одно изображение 500x500, а второе 1000x1000. Каждый из объектов `Image` можно перемещать мышкой по `Scrollpane`, по этому каждый из них может быть на разном расстоянии друг от друга. С учётом всех расстояний и габаритов Images, ширина и высота контентной области объекта Scrollpane может быть равна примерно 1600х1100 - вот это значение мне и нужно получать.

*Я в Java новенький. Но, знаю, что на некоторые свойства объектов можно повесить обработчик событий.
Подскажите пожалуйста, какой обработчик для `Scrollpane` мне требуется использовать.*

Comment: Т.е. у тебя есть объект, у него высота 1000px, а в скролпайне видно только 200px. Тебе нужно получить эти 200px?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov все немного сложней. У меня есть несколько объектов в Scrollpane, каждый из которых может находится на разном расстоянии друг от друга, и каждый из которых может иметь разные размеры. В runtime кол-во объектов в Scrollpane может увеличиваться или уменьшаться.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov собственно мне нужно получить реальную ширину/высоту области которая скролиться (с учётом той области, которая скрыта и её нужно скролить). И получать мне эти значения нужно каждый раз, когда размеры контентной части Scrollpane изменяются.

Comment: Что ты подразумеваешь под "ширину/высоту области которая скролиться"? посмотри мой перввый комментарий, какое тебе число надо получить? 1000 или 200? Если ни одно из этих, то напиши в вопросе простой пример, с числами, что ты ожидаешь.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov дополнил описание вопроса.

Comment: тогда в твоем случае, нужно положить в скролпайн какой -либо контейнер (VBox, GridPane и тому подобные) и уже брать высоту этого контейнера методо getHeight()

Comment: @AndrewBystrov спасибо, это помогло. `Pane` в качестве контейнера идеально подошел.